# Element is added in wrong place and how to add another sub-element?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xml-parsing

I have following code written:

```
public static void AddUploadToXML(XDocument xdoc, int id, string fileHash, string fileName)
    {
        var singleUpload = new XElement("upload",
            new XAttribute("backupid", id),
            new XElement("file", fileHash),
            new XAttribute("filename", fileName)
            );
        xdoc.Root.Add(singleUpload);
    }
```

In the effect I want to to get XML like this:

```
<uploads>
  <upload backupid="3" >
    <file filename=""></file>
  </upload>
</uploads>
```

But I finish with something like this:

```
<uploads>
  <upload backupid="3" filename="">
    <file></file>
  </upload>
</uploads>
```

Another problem is:

1.How to modify that filename attribute in other part of the app (it will be first file element under upload element with given ID),

2.THEN, how to add other file elements, to finish with something like this:

```
<uploads>
  <upload backupid="3" >
    <file filename="Test.001">HASHCODE</file>
    <file filename="Test.002">HASHCODE2</file>
    <file filename="Test.003">HASHCODE3</file>
  </upload>
  <upload backupid="4" >
    <file filename="Test2.001">HASHCODE</file>
    (...)
  </upload>
</uploads>
```

Comment: make another XElement for file. And add that element in singleUpload element,

Comment: I will prefer you use XML serializable tags. Make classes for Upload, File etc. That is easy to manage, and is automatic,

Comment: I agree with @FaisalHafeez, don't do complex (or even simple) xml like this. The quality of the question on the other hand makes me believe that you have a hard time with xml, so my actual recommendation is to fool around a bit with xml before you come back and attack this problem.

Comment: Thanks for the idea! Do you have any example maybe for that?

Comment: @flindeberg: I need xml for that, because over the time this "database" of files should consists of thousands of records. And yes, I have a lot of dizzy problems with xml and I couldn't find a single simple and neat tutorial for that :-(

Comment: Follow this. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58a18dwa(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first you should change your method to smth like this:

```
public static void AddUploadToXML(XDocument xdoc, int id, string fileHash, string fileName)
    {
        var singleUpload = new XElement("upload",
            new XAttribute("backupid", id),
            new XElement("file", fileHash,
                new XAttribute("filename", fileName))
            );
        xdoc.Root.Add(singleUpload);
    }
```

As for the second question: you should load xml file or parse xml string

```
XElement.Load(file path) / XElement.Parse(xml string)
```

and then you need to find needed "upload" node by Id and add new "file" node:

```
    var element = singleUpload.Elements("upload").SingleOrDefault(x => x.Attribute("backupid").Value == "3");
    element.Add( new XElement("file", "123", new XAttribute("filename", "1223")));
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip! Can you please tell me, what "element" should point to? I keep getting null for that. I mean, why element should have to do something with "singleUpload" instead of whole xml file?

Comment: I modified a code a bit like this: var element = xdoc.Elements("upload"). (...) and it is not what it's looking for. Should I somehow provide root path?

Comment: I've used "singleUpload" name from your example, in my case its XElement loaded from xml file or string. Can you please tell me what exception you r getting when trying to use my code from example? If your xml structure same as you defined it in your first post - all should work fine.

Comment: I don't want to provide that part to other method. What seems to be a problem with such line: xdoc.Elements("upload").SingleOrDefault(x => x.Attribute("backupid").Value.Equals(lastUsedID)); ?

Answer (score 0):

You need an array object[] like this

```
public static void AddUploadToXML(XDocument xdoc, int id, string fileHash, string fileName)
        {
            var singleUpload = new XElement("upload", new object[] {
                new XAttribute("backupid", id),
                new XElement("file", new object[] {new XAttribute("filename", fileName), fileHash})
            });
            xdoc.Root.Add(singleUpload);

        }
```